# Reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, lts, 18.04

I have been running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in 4 partitions.
Partition 1  Boot
Partition 2  System
Partition 3  Home
Partition 4  Swap

I have a boot-able DVD.

Question?
How can I reinstall the boot and system partition **without** disturbing my Home partition?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has a choice to install with **manual partitioning (something else)**... (You possibly used it to create the current system [or someone else did it for you]).

When you chose manual partitioning, you have the option to format, or to not format the partition (there you have to chose "**Don't format**" and "**use as /home**").

Everything else is a normal installation process.